# How to add multiple HttpPost method in one controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm creating a simple ASP.NET MVC web app. In my controller I have two HttpPost methods and I call two different stored procedures. Everything worked well until I added a second HttpPost method. Now I have a problem with the second HttpPost method - when I click on it ("Go to view") I get a message

> Unable to find matching view

My controller:

```
    //...
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {        
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index(OrderListOfClass ttt)
        {
           //code
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index(OrderListOfClass ttt, string send)
        {
            //calling stored procedure 1
        }

        [ActionName("Tank")]
        public ActionResult Tank(OrderListOfClass ttt)
        {
           //code
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Tank")]
        public ActionResult Tank(OrderListOfClass ttt, string sendBatch)
        {
            //calling stored procedure 2
        }
    }
```

My view:

```
@model SlurryOrderTest.Models.OrderListOfClass
//...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //textbox to be filled by user - input parameter for stored procedure 1
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //textbox which are filled by stored procedure 1
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Tank", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //textbox to be filled by user - input parameter for stored procedure 2
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Tank", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
   //textbox which are filled by stored procedure 2
}
```

Why doesn't the "Tank" action go into a view?
I'm probably making some stupid mistake but C# is a new language for me :(

Comment: Do you have a `Tank` view?

Comment: No. Should I add it to the Order folder?

Comment: Well it depends. If you want the Tank action to have it's own view, then yes, you obviously need a view called Tank

Comment: @KwiecMac:  In the controller, Your method name `Test` and action name `Test` both are the same. Use unique and meaningful methodName and then call accordingly from your view. Hopefully, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to tell it which view to use.  By default it will look for one called tank.cshtml in the Views\Order folder.  So I think you need this for your tank method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Tank")]
    public ActionResult Tank(OrderListOfClass ttt, string sendBatch)
    {
        //calling stored procedure 2
        return View("Index", ttt);
    }
```

Alternatively if you want it to go to its own specific view then create a tank view by creating a file call Tank.cshtml in the order folder.

Comment: Thanks but i tried these. Now i discover that my problem is probably another. When I'm opening my view i got message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."                                                                                                            
```@using (Html.BeginForm("Tank", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.TankList.TankName, Model.TankList.TankName.ToString())
} ```

Comment: @KwiecMac To get a good answer I would suggest editing your original question to include these details.  You will also need to include more details about the contents of your tank post method.

Comment: @KwiecMac please don't ask multiple questions in one question. If this answer answers your immediate question then you should mark it as accepted, if you have another problem then you should add another question

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to understand when calling controller methods.

1. In order to go to the view from the controller by right click you probably need to have a view within the views folder with the same name as that method.
2. In a controller if there are two methods with the same name and if one has an [HttpPost] attribute then it will be called from Form.Post in view. If the other method has no attribute then it will automatically be the get method.